# Chat Android Socket x Firebase

Tags: android, chat

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a criação de um *chat* simples(nunca implementei um ), andei pesquisando e vi a implementação do Firebase, ele me fornece toda uma estrutura para criação, estou na dúvida quais vantagens e desvantagens de um e outro. desde já agradeço

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta que depende muito da arquitetura planejada. Da pra fazer com os dois, a diferença é que o socket você tem somente comunicação p2p diretamente entre os aparelhos. No firebase, você vai mandar para um repositório, e depois ler estes valores. Mas também pode deixar listeners abertos para que essa comunicação seja automática.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática exatamente! eu digo em termos de performance e as vantagens e desvantagens, ainda estou analisando

Comment: Penso que com o Firebase seria mais simples, porque te tira o peso de ter que, por exemplo, planejar armazenamento temporário no aparelho, e ficar verificando se tem novas mensagens e tauz com jobs.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática hmmm! é isso que to analisando, acho que vou implementar das duas formas